# Remove Bullet Points from a Wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress

Have setup a Wordpress site (V3.1.2) and have installed Download Monitor plugin to give me a [downloads gallery](http://www.dekho.com.au/download-gallery/).

The issue is that I get these blue bullet points next to download items in the left column:
[image]

It has its own CSS file, but from using Chrome Developer tools, it appears that it is picking up these bullet points from my Boldy theme:

```
#content #colLeft ul li, #content #colLeft ol li {
padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
background: url(images/bullet_list.png) 0 8px no-repeat;
```

I am new to CSS and I am sure this is a noob question.

How can I create a rule to remove bullet points from this download gallery, whilst preserving the fact that in blog posts (like [this](http://www.dekho.com.au/crystal-reports-performance/)), I can still make use of bullet points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a CSS rule to remove the bullets on your downloads page only:

```
#content #colLeft #download-page ul li,
#content #colLeft #download-page ol li{
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    background: none;
}
```

This rule targets lists inside the #download-page div. It can be placed in your main stylesheet to override the default bullet styling.

Comment: I pasted this within my Styles.css, and did a hard refresh on my downloads page = no change.  What am I missing?

Comment: My mistake -- I accidentally put the #download-page before the #colLeft instead of after it. Please use the updated code above and try again. It should work fine now.